# C# AWS SDK SecurityTokenServiceClient.AssumeRole returning "SignatureDoesNotMatch" 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been implementing an AWS S3 integration with the C# AWS SDK in a development environment, and everything has been going well. Part of the requirement is that the IAM AccessKey and SecretKey rotate, and the credential/config files stored or cached, and there is also a Role to be assumed in the process.

I have a method which returns credentials after initializing a `AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient` with AccessKey, SecretKey, and RegionEndpoint, formats a `AssumeRoleRequest` with the RoleArn and then executes the request:

```cs
using (var STSClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey, bucketRegion))
{
    try
    {
        var response = STSClient.AssumeRole(new AssumeRoleRequest(roleARN));

        if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) return response.Credentials;
    }
    catch (AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is simplified, as the real implementation validates the credential variables, etc.. And it matches the AWS Developer code examples (although I can't find the link to that page anymore).

This has been working in dev just fine. Having moved this to a QA env with new AWS credentials, which I've been assured have been set up in the same process as the dev credentials, I'm now receiving an exception on the AssumeRole call.

The actual AssumeRole method doesn't include documentation that it would throw that exception, it's just the one it raises. The StatusCode: 403 Forbidden, ErrorCode: SignatureDoesNotMatch, ErrorType: Sender, Message "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided....".

Things I have ruled out:

- Keys are correct and do not contain escaped characters (/), or leading/trailing spaces
- bucket region is correct us-west-2
- sts auth region is us-east-1
- SignatureVersion is 4

Switching back to the dev keys works, but that is not a production-friendly solution. Ultimately I will not be in charge of the keys, or the Aws account to create them. I've been in touch with the IT Admin who created the accounts/keys/roles and he assured me they are created the same way I created the dev accounts/keys/roles (which was an agreed-upon process prior to development).

The provided accounts/keys/roles can be accessed via the CLI or web console, so I can confirm they work and are active. I've been diligent to not have any CLI created credential or config files floating around that the sdk might access by default.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You have successfully authorized, your key is correct, but it might be missing a required scope to access certain resource that's exactly what 403 is.

Comment: Well, that's reassuring that the key is correct. Regarding scope, I thought the RoleARN would define that. At the point of getting the assumed role credentials, it wouldn't know what resource (presigned url in this case) will be requested. There is a property to define a policy, but the role has full access, so that's a bit counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why AWS returns this error is usually that the **secret key** is **incorrect**

*The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch)*